# RFID Access Memory Bank

Tags: c#, rfid, motorola, motorola-emdk

I want to access the internal MemoryBank of a RFID UHF Tag.
I'm using the [Inline Tag Plate Monza 3 from HID](https://www.hidglobal.com/doclib/files/resource_files/hid-rfid-il-inline-tag-plate-ds-en.pdf)! and the Motorola FX7400 Reader.

The tag has a 64 Bit TID Memory.
My Code

```
TagAccess.ReadAccessParams readParams = new TagAccess.ReadAccessParams();   
TagData readAccessTag;   
readParams.AccessPassword = 0;   
readParams.ByteCount = 8;
readParams.MemoryBank = MEMORY_BANK.MEMORY_BANK_TID;
readParams.ByteOffset = 0;
readAccessTag = rfidreader.Actions.TagAccess.ReadWait(tagID, readParams, null); //Crash here

Console.WriteLine(readAccessTag.MemoryBank.ToString() + " : " + readAccessTag.MemoryBankData);
```

The program crashes as soon as I execute the ReadWait line. But with no exception.

Even in the example program from the Motorola Reader I cannot read the Memory.

I tried with several different ByteCounts and Offsets. But it didn't work.

Can you guys help me?

(Sorry for bad english :) )